# Microsoft SQL Query Help insert records based on template records. (Employees / Jobs)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am no Expert but I am stuck trying to figure out the best method to accomplish my goals.
Problem:

Table of employees [EMPLOYEES] and table of allowed job codes [EMPTRANSRATES] both tables have a column called "filekey" its a 1 to many relationship.

I have several Template employees with an "IDNUM" that starts with "T" and many employees with "IDNUM" that are just numbers. These employees also have a crew identifier called "WG1". I need to insert into [EMPTRANSRATES] all of the records of the [EMPTRANSRATES] records of Template Employees with the filekey of any [EMPLOYEE] with a matching "WG1".

Proposed solution:

Use a cursor to build a list of filekey of employees with a specific "WG1" and in the cursor select into the [EMPTRANSRATES] table. - I dont like this solution because I will have to make one for each distinct WG1.

Question 1. Can I put a cursor in a cursor? For example generate a list of each distinct WG1 temmplate employee and in that select all employees file keys that have a matching WG1 and finally for each insert matching emptransrates with the unique file keys for each employee.

Question 2. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Brad

*EDIT*

```
Example of data
    [EMPLOYEES]
    |FILEKEY|FNAME|LNAME|IDNUM|WG1|
    1,Brad,Williams,1234,2
    2,Template,Template,T2,2
    3,Template.Template,T17,17
    4,Stan,Smith,0531,2
    5,Sally,Smith,9876,17

    [EMPTRANSRATES]
    |FILEKEY|JOB1|JOB2|
    2,1,0
    2,1,1
    2,2,0
    2,0,3
    3,1,1
    3,0,7

Expected results of script
    [EMPLOYEES]
    |FILEKEY|FNAME|LNAME|IDNUM|WG1|
    1,Brad,Williams,1234,2
    2,Template1,Template1,T2,2
    3,Template2.Template2,T17,17
    4,Stan,Smith,0531,2
    5,Sally,Smith,9876,17

    [EMPTRANSRATES]
    |FILEKEY|JOB1|JOB2|
    2,1,0
    2,1,1
    2,2,0
    2,0,3
    3,1,1
    3,0,7
    1,1,0
    1,1,1
    1,2,0
    1,0,3
    4,1,0
    4,1,1
    4,2,0
    4,0,3
    5,1,1
    5,0,7
```

Because filekey 1 and filekey 4 were the same WG1 as the template1 employee new records were created for their filekeys in the emptransrats table copied from the matching template employee.

Because filekey 5 was the same WG1 as the template2 employee new records were created for the filekeys in the emptransrats table copied from the matching template employee.

Thanks again.

Comment: never use a cursor in sql --sql works with sets of data that is how you should do it.

Comment: the way you have this worded is hard to follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the edit this is what I understand (thinking in sets)

1. Select all templates (denoted as IDNUM starts with "T") from employee.
2. Select all employees (denoted as IDNUM without "T") from employee table that have a matching WG1 number to those templates.
3. Insert into EMPTRANSRATES those values that match the template but with the employees id.

Now that we understand it as operations on a set lets take it step by step.

Select all templates

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEES AS T -- T stands for Template
WHERE T.IDNUM LIKE 'T%'
```

Select employees with matching

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEES E
JOIN EMPLOYEES T ON E.WG1 = T.WG1 AND T.IDNUM LIKE 'T%'
WHERE NOT E.IDNUM LIKE 'T%'
```

Now before we can use this to insert we need the values from the other table, just join it:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEES E
JOIN EMPLOYEES T ON E.WG1 = T.WG1 AND T.IDNUM LIKE 'T%'
JOIN EMPTRANSRATES R ON T.FILEKEY = R.FILEKEY
WHERE NOT E.IDNUM LIKE 'T%'
```

Done, just add in the insert:

```
INSERT INTO EMPTRANSRATES (FILEKEY, JOB1, JOB2)
  SELECT E.FILEKEY, R.JOB1, R.JOB2
  FROM EMPLOYEES E
  JOIN EMPLOYEES T ON E.WG1 = T.WG1 AND T.IDNUM LIKE 'T%'
  JOIN EMPTRANSRATES R ON T.FILEKEY = R.FILEKEY
  WHERE NOT E.IDNUM LIKE 'T%'
```

> Please don't just copy the answer and run it.  **Instead** run each step and make sure you understand what it is doing.  Otherwise my bothering to answer this question and do it in a way that was clear was *a total waste of time* for both of us.   This is fairly basic SQL and you should have been able to figure it out -- I hope the way I explained it gets you "thinking in SQL."  **Don't use cursors!**

### -------

Very hard to tell from your question but I expect you want something that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO EMPTRANSRATE ({Columns to populate})
  SELECT DISTINCT {What you need to insert}
  FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE IDNUM LIKE 'T%' 
    AND CREW_IDENTIFIER = 'WG1'
```

If you are worried that the columns already exist in EMPTRANSRATE you can fix that like this (assuming columns need are A and B)

```
INSERT INTO EMPTRANSRATE (A, B)
  SELECT DISTINCT A, B
  FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE IDNUM LIKE 'T%' 
    AND CREW_IDENTIFIER = 'WG1'
    AND (A, B) NOT IN
        (SELECT A, B FROM EMPTRANSRATE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I am going to show some sample data so you can better see what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok I edited my question with an example if you could be so kind as to review that please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working version of my code and works well. Thank you all that have helped!

```
INSERT INTO EMPTRANRATES (FILEKEY, FLAGS, WG1,WG2,WG3, RATE,EFFDATE,DTTMSTAMP,WG4,WG5,WG6,WG7)
  SELECT Distinct E.FILEKEY, R.FLAGS, r.WG1,r.WG2,r.WG3, r.RATE,r.EFFDATE,r.DTTMSTAMP,r.WG4,r.WG5,r.WG6,r.WG7
  FROM EMPLOYEES E
  JOIN EMPLOYEES T ON E.WG1 = T.WG1 AND T.IDNUM LIKE 'T%'
  JOIN EMPTRANRATES R ON T.FILEKEY = R.FILEKEY
  WHERE NOT E.IDNUM LIKE 'T%'
  AND not exists
    (Select FILEKEY, FLAGS, WG1,WG2,WG3, RATE,EFFDATE,DTTMSTAMP,WG4,WG5,WG6,WG7 from EMPTRANRATES)
```

In the end I used not exists because I was having an error.

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
```

The code I was using before the change was:

```
INSERT INTO EMPTRANRATES (FILEKEY, FLAGS, WG1,WG2,WG3, RATE,EFFDATE,DTTMSTAMP,WG4,WG5,WG6,WG7)
  SELECT Distinct E.FILEKEY, R.FLAGS, r.WG1,r.WG2,r.WG3, r.RATE,r.EFFDATE,r.DTTMSTAMP,r.WG4,r.WG5,r.WG6,r.WG7
  FROM EMPLOYEES E
  JOIN EMPLOYEES T ON E.WG1 = T.WG1 AND T.IDNUM LIKE 'T%'
  JOIN EMPTRANRATES R ON T.FILEKEY = R.FILEKEY
  WHERE NOT E.IDNUM LIKE 'T%'
  AND (E.FILEKEY, R.FLAGS, r.WG1,r.WG2,r.WG3, r.RATE,r.EFFDATE,r.DTTMSTAMP,r.WG4,r.WG5,r.WG6,r.WG7) not in
    (Select FILEKEY, FLAGS, WG1,WG2,WG3, RATE,EFFDATE,DTTMSTAMP,WG4,WG5,WG6,WG7 from EMPTRANRATES)
```

That code threw flags and did not process. I am not sure why but it works with NOT EXISTS

Thanks again everyone!